# Rounding only bottom anchor points using direct selection tool

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs6

Using **Adobe Illustrator CS6**, I'm trying to select only the bottom anchor points using the Direct Selection Tool. And apply the following effect: Effect > Stylize > Round Corners

However, all the four anchor points get transformed when I try to do that (I clicked on bottom anchor points only using the direct selection tool).

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I can't remember if that feature exists in cs6, but [Round any corner script](http://shspage.com/aijs/en#roundany) works in cs3 and up.  Download link for the whole package at the top.

Comment: If you search the site for rounding corners in Illustrator there are a ton of questions already related to this: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=illustrator%20round%20corners

Answer (score 1):

There is good and simple way to do that[image]